# How can I prevent my divs from overlapping, when the browser window is shrunk?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to build a site that will act as my "resume" to replace an old one I have, using the new things I have learned. I haven't gotten very far however, I have run into an issue that, whenever I shrink the browser window, my tags then overlap.

I have adjusted the position to have them sit in the window exactly where I want them, but even using percentages they will still overlap. I have tried adjusting the position attribute to fixed, absolute (best one, but still overlaps) and other combinations of the other values. I have also tried adjusting margins\padding but they just keep it sitting there.

```css
/* nav-menu settings*/

.navMenu {
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.navMenu a {
  background-color: #3F025B;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 3px ridge;
  border-color: #A17500;
  text-align: center;
}

.navMenu a:hover {
  background-color: #00B4FF;
  color: #282941;
}

.navMenu a.active {
  background-color: #E727C6;
  /* Add a green color to the "active/current" link */
  color: black;
}


/* background settings */

HTML {
  background-image: url("SynthwaveHorizon.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Scrollbar settings */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #00B4FF;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}


/*Below is styling specific to the Home page */

.artBox {
  height: 85%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  opacity: .8;
  border: 5px inset pink;
}

.defyBox {
  width: 75%;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.blinking {
  animation: blinkingText 1s infinite;
  font: bold;
}

@keyframes blinkingText {
  0% {
    color: orange;
  }
  49% {
    color: purple;
  }
  100% {
    color: hotpink;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="background">

  <div class="navMenu">
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#">
      <div>Link 1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    <a href="#">Link 8</a>
    <a href="#">Link 9</a>
  </div>

  <div class="defyBox">
    <p id="loader" class="blinking">
      Pretending to load something!<br> ...
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class="artBox">
  </div>

</body>
```

I would of thought setting absolute would force it to keep its dimensions, but while I am sure that is true, its simply because the "menu" and "box" sizes are too wide to play nice with how this is set up.

Comment: You will likely want to look at something designed to be a bit more "stretchy" like CSS grids: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid or CSS Flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox to keep your content in logical columns/rows but adapt as needed to different screen sizes.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fjev2Lxt/ but i can't figure out what is your goal...

Comment: witch tag do overlap?

Comment: The specific tags that overlap are the "navMenu" and the "artBox"

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still unclear to me, how they overlap? if you shrink the page vertically?

Comment: They overlap when shrinking the browser in any directions, especially shrinking width.